# Sort Table using comparator AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is there a way for me to sort the table content based on internal comparator?

For example, I want to display my own date format as custom format (Wednesday, 3:00 am). But when I click the table head it should sort based on the actual time bind to that cell. I am not sure how to bind the cell and display different data. I managed to do simple sorting alphabetically based on the display data, but is it possible to do what I just described?

Comment: You can sort **data** based on anything you like.  It sounds like you are specifically asking about some sort of directive that generates a table from your data, but without a [mcve] of your issue, it's really not possible to tell you the specifics of how to accomplish this task.

Comment: Date formatting can (and even should in Angular) be done using [filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_09), sorting will then use the original value.